# moving async core data fetch to extensions

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, extension-methods

I cannot find a way to make this func reusable in my app (Swift 4.2), I'd like to add to UIViewController via extension, but I think it is not allowed somehow. Even using inout issue seems to be unresolved when moving and manipulating it to be "reusable" in the rest of app I got most of all two errors:

if I try to set a method argument "asyncFetch: NSAsynchronousFetchRequest" I go error Cannot assign to value: 'asyncFetch' is a 'let' constant, same erro if I try to add an argument for the array

second error happens when I try to make the func return an array of NSmanagedObject, and I cannot use guard statement since they "return" are intended as return of the func itself (and more, since is async, cannot return an array filled, but only empty one)

```
    func asyncFetchAllEntities() {

        print("Fetching all entities...")

        asyncPersonEntityArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)


        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let personFetch : NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
        //here you can add some predicate

        //this block makes the fetch Asynch - start :
        //************************************************************************************
        asyncFetchRequest = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest<Person>(fetchRequest: personFetch) {
            [unowned self] (result: NSAsynchronousFetchResult) in
            guard let allPersonsResult = result.finalResult else {
                return
            }

            self.asyncPersonEntityArray = allPersonsResult

            //here you can do what you need - start :
            //************************************

            do {
                self.asyncPersonEntityArray = try managedContext.fetch(personFetch)
                if self.asyncPersonEntityArray.count > 0 {
                    print("OK - asyncFetchAllEntities: - entity model is not empty!") //
                } else {
//                    self.myPersErrorMessage(errorMessage: "WARNING! - no entitites error 1")
                    print("WARNING! - no entitites error 1")
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("WARNING! - asyncFetchAllEntities: Fetch error: \(error) description: \(error.userInfo)")
            }


            guard self.asyncPersonEntityArray != nil else {return}


            //here you can do all you want as updating tableview, make som check, etc:


            for personFound in self.asyncPersonEntityArray {

                let personToPrint = personFound as! Person

                guard personToPrint.name != nil else {
                    print("WARNING! : - name was nil!!")
                    return
                }

                print("Name is: \(personToPrint.name!) and age: \(personToPrint.age)")


            }


            print("...Fetched all entitites")


            //here you can do what you need - end :
            //************************************
        }
        //this block makes the fetch Asynch - end :
        //************************************************************************************

        // MARK: - async fetch request 3
        do {
            try managedContext.execute(asyncFetchRequest)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("WARNING! - asyncFetchAllEntities: Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        print("OK! - fetched completed")

        //end of function
    }
```

Comment: I fail to see the issues you’re describing in your code, it’s like the code is another version. Maybe you should focus on one issue at the time and describe better where in your code this issue happens.

Comment: First thing why you want to pass "asyncFetch: NSAsynchronousFetchRequest" as a parameter? For Second error - Try completion block instead simply return array. Return your array in completion block.